# Import npm packages

Tags: rollupjs

How should I import npm packages? If I just add lodash bundling goes from 6ms to 900ms!?
Is there no way to cache static dependencies?
If I add lodash to `external`, `globals` and `customResolveOptions` in `rollup.config.js` it is excluded from the bundle. But how could I add it in a `libs.js` file for example?

Here are my files:

**app.js**

```
import _ from 'lodash'

alert(_.concat(["hi", "hello"]))
```

**rollup.config.js**

```
import resolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve';
import commonjs from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs';
import uglify from 'rollup-plugin-uglify';
import babel from 'rollup-plugin-babel';

const production = !process.env.ROLLUP_WATCH;

export default {
    input: 'src/index.js',
    output: {
        file: 'scripts/bundle.js',
        format: 'iife',
        sourcemap: true
    },
    plugins: [
        resolve(),
        commonjs(),
        babel({
          exclude: 'node_modules/**'
        }),
        production && uglify()
    ]
};
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.2",
    "rollup": "^0.55.5",
    "rollup-plugin-commonjs": "^8.0.2",
    "rollup-plugin-node-resolve": "^3.0.0",
    "rollup-plugin-uglify": "^3.0.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-plugin-external-helpers": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "rollup-plugin-babel": "^3.0.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "lodash": "^4.17.10"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "rollup -c",
    "watch": "rollup -c -w",
    "dev": "npm-run-all --parallel watch"
  },
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually separate the entrypoints for "libs" and source code to speed up your build:

**rollup.config.js**

```
import resolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve';
import commonjs from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs';
import uglify from 'rollup-plugin-uglify';
import babel from 'rollup-plugin-babel';

const production = !process.env.ROLLUP_WATCH;

export default [{
    input: 'src/index.js',
    output: {
        file: 'scripts/bundle.js',
        format: 'iife',
        sourcemap: true,
        globals: {
            'lodash': '_',
        },
    },
    external: ['lodash'],
    plugins: [
        babel(),
        production && uglify()
    ]
}, {
    input: 'src/common.js',
    output: {
        file: 'scripts/common.js',
        format: 'umd',
        name: 'window',
        extend: true,
        sourcemap: true
    },
    plugins: [
        resolve(),
        commonjs(),
        production && uglify()
    ]
}];
```

**common.js**

```
export { default as _ } from 'lodash'
```

It does add the overhead of maintaining the `common.js` file with libraries. Personally, I find it gives the best control over file size and compile time. If you're constantly installing and including new npm packages, this will be be hard to maintain.

Comment: WOW thank you! just what I was looking for!
I found that you even can set `name` to "window" and add `extend:true`, then you can just do `lodash: '_'` in globals :)

Comment: That's a little cleaner. Updating my answer to that for future reference.

Comment: You can also use `export from`, see updated common.js.